# How to manage multiple account login in Django

Tags: django

I creating a page which already login with account's user and has a link to do login with another account. But I have no idea, yet. Anyone have some cool idea?

Comment: Are you saying that you need to have someone logged in as multiple accounts at once?

Comment: I mean user already login, after that user need to login with another account.

Answer (score 0):

Django's session engine manages per-user sessions, i.e. each user (`auth.User` instance) gets a single session, his own.

While that does mean you have to track each user under a single `auth.User` instance, it doesn't mean you can't create a `UserProfile` that will implement a custom layer which tracks multiple *accounts* (I'd use this term loosely) with an single `auth.User` instance.

That's what you usually do if you accept multiple login mechanisms. For instance, your users may have an existing account to which they can log in using their registered `username`, `password`, *but* they can also login via OpenID or their Facebook account.